# Angular 2 doesn't see the file even if it is exist (using Angular-cli)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

Actually I got a stylesheet:
`<link href="../node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">`

That file exist, the Webstorm also sees that file in the directory, but somehow Angular2 is unable to load it.

> Error: GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css

**How to make Angular2 load that file?**
Thanks for any further informations.

The root looks like:

-Main folder

--node_modules

---stuff

--src

---index.html

---styles.css

**EDIT**
On `mithunvp.com/angular-material-2-angular-cli-webpack/` there's a hint to use

> @import '~https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
>
> @import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css';

to turn on a prebuilt theme. But once again, even if it's pasted inside the `styles.css` it returns errors that it cant find it. It cant even find the Material icons, which is a link...

Comment: @DanielA.White What do you mean by web server?

Comment: what is driving port 4200?

Comment: @DanielA.White ng serve in Angular 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to load css like that, even more when you can have sccs source file.

Using `angular-cli`, I can imagine that you have the file `src/styles.scss` or `.less` right ? (unless you decided to use pure css ?!).

So if you're using sass, in `src/styles.scss` just put :
`@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css';`

Plus, I can imagine what you're trying to do and if you haven't seen Kara's demo with angular-material, I'd recommend you to take a look to : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0q9FOeEELPY

Comment: Im doing everything like in that movie, but somehow Angular2 cant find these files. She is doing it at 4:00 in the movie, everything works for her, but my Angular2 cant find these files.  `@import '~https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css';`

Comment: It's fixed. Thank u

Comment: what did you do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To Fix the Issue, Please Inline **styles.css** from index.html and add it inside angular-cli.json under style Array like

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
```

Hope. It will work

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You should use the following statement

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

instead of

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

inside the `styles.css`.